# VS Code - Files in same folder using different versions of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm having a really annoying issue in VS Code. I'm working out of one folder. In this folder are multiple sub-folders. I'm running a file in one of these sub-folders which references files from other sub-folders. For some reason this main file is using a different version of python than one of the referenced files. When I run each file individually I get the expected output for python version: 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

However when I just run the main file, the referenced file is shown to be using an older version of python: 3.9.6 (default, Aug 15 2021, 14:49:43)  [GCC 10.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] This causes all kinds of problems with installed packages. How do I deal with this?

Comment: It cannot be, sorry. I think you're missing something

Comment: @user70 I am running print(sys.version) and that's exactly the output I'm getting. I have selected the right interpreter in vscode.

Comment: gcc-Python is compiled for Linux or for MSYS2 or Cygwin, MSC-Python is compiled for Windows

Comment: @rioV8 I know, I've got no idea why it's defaulting to gcc. I did nothing to select that and I haven't encountered this issue before.

Comment: Are you using subprocess or something like it?

Comment: @JonSG Yes, subprocess is used in the referenced file (the one causing the problem)

Comment: One suggestion, try using [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command). If it doesn't work, please check your Shebang Line and check your code for subprocess calls.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT There are subprocess calls, how should I deal with that?

Comment: If your main file is running the referenced files as subprocesses (using subprocess.run(), for example), 
it might be using the system's default Python interpreter instead of the one specified in VS Code. 
Make sure to specify the full path to the correct Python interpreter in your subprocess calls.